# Convert SortDirection to string - error TS2322

Tags: angular

StrictTemplate is complaining that a SortDirection is not a string. However, an enum is a string, isn't it?

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'SortDirection'.

`<mat-table matSort matSortDirection="{{ this.sort.direction }}" ...`

The definition of SortDirection is:

> export declare type SortDirection = 'asc' | 'desc' | '';

Is there a way to convert it to string?

I tried `matSortDirection="{{(string)this.sort.direction}}"` and `matSortDirection="{{this.sort.direction.toString()}}"` but fail.

What's the best way to convert it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought and came to the conclusion that the problem is that I'm converting to string when I use interpolation. It is correct to use binding.

```
[matSortDirection]="sort.direction"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add helper `$any` to say to compiler, that nothing is wrong here and everything is correct

```
<mat-table matSort matSortDirection="{{ $any(this.sort.direction) }}" ...
```

or

```
export class Component {

  get direction(): SortDirection {
    return this.sort.direction as SortDirection;
  }
}

<mat-table matSort matSortDirection="{{ direction }}" ...
```

Comment: I would not like to escape the value, but rather convert to string. I would have to do this inside the component right?

Comment: yes, have added to answer

Comment: @RodrigoLanes, what is the aims of this? I imagine you has an unique MatSort that you get using ViewChild. So the matSort always has the direction of this.sort.direction -it's the same- :(